# Failure Of Backup Due To Limit Exceeded For Recovery Files Since Cannot Reclaim Disk Space [RMAN-03009,ORA-19809,ORA-19804]

Tags: backup, oracle-11g-r2, disk-space, rman, errors

While I try to take incremental backup level 0 by using the command

> RMAN> backup incremental level 0 database plus archivelog;

, encountered this error.

```
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================

RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at 08/27/2013 15:58:
05
ORA-19809: limit exceeded for recovery files
ORA-19804: cannot reclaim 52428800 bytes disk space from 4327473152 limit
```

When I went through some forums, I found a lot of solutions, but when I checked with their situations, it doesn't match.

- One solution was to increase the db_recovery space. So I checked the space and got this result.

*db_recovery size*

```
 SQL> show parameter db_recovery;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_recovery_file_dest                string      /u01/app/oracle/fast_recovery_
                                                 area
db_recovery_file_dest_size           big integer 4127M
```

*Space Usage*

```
SQL> select SPACE_USED,SPACE_LIMIT from  v$recovery_file_dest;

SPACE_USED SPACE_LIMIT
---------- -----------
 800155136  4327473152
```

*Available Space*

```
 SQL>SELECT
NAME,
TO_CHAR(SPACE_LIMIT, '999,999,999,999') AS SPACE_LIMIT,
TO_CHAR(SPACE_LIMIT - SPACE_USED + SPACE_RECLAIMABLE,
'999,999,999,999') AS SPACE_AVAILABLE,
ROUND((SPACE_USED - SPACE_RECLAIMABLE)/SPACE_LIMIT * 100, 1)
AS PERCENT_FULL
FROM V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST;

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SPACE_LIMIT      SPACE_AVAILABLE  PERCENT_FULL
---------------- ---------------- ------------
/u01/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area
   4,327,473,152    3,488,460,800         19.4
```

*From RMAN*

```
RMAN> show all;

RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name AGGE are:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1; # default
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE MAXSETSIZE TO UNLIMITED; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES128'; # default
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'BASIC' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE ; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO NONE; # default
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/dbs/snapcf_agge.f'; # default
```

What should I do to resolve this problem? Do I have to increase the recovery space even after I am having this much space?

Using ORACLE 11G R2 in RHEL5

Answer (score 2):

The `db_recovery_file_dest` includes a variety of files, including online AND archived redo log files; take a look at the Oracle Backup and Recovery User's Guide [chapter 5](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmconfb.htm#BRADV89418) to find out the best solution; disabling `db_recovery_file_dest` is not a good idea.  You can try

```
RMAN> report obsolete;
```

RMAN command to see what can be deleted. Then do a `delete obsolete` to delete them. Do you have any guaranteed restore points defined?

```
RMAN> list restore point all;
```

If you see any results with type GUARANTEED, if they are no longer needed, remove them:

```
SQL> DROP RESTORE POINT before_app_upgrade;
```

Is flashback database enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same issue. I tried the options mentioned above as well, to no avail. Finally, as suggested by a friend, disabling the `db_recovery_file_dest` solved the issue for me.

```
SQL> alter system set db_recovery_file_dest='' scope=both;
```

Comment: This _may_ work if you have Oracle managed files, or ASM; it won't be a long term fix.